# Relation between Lattice and Boolean Algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, lattices

In discrete math, I have read that lattice is a generalized form of boolean lattice. But those places where boolean algebra is mentioned, they don't tell about lattices (digital logic, binary,...). Whether the **meet** and **join** is same as **and** and **or** in *boolean logic*? If we are thinking in terms of lattices how you define **1 and 0 = 0**? We consider only a two element lattice?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order), http://matt.might.net/articles/partial-orders/

Answer (score 4):

I would hardly describe a lattice as a generalized form of boolean algebra, since there are *many* more things that a lattice can describe.

A better description would be to say that boolean algebra forms an extremely simple lattice. It has two elements, $\top$ and $\bot$, with $\bot \sqsubset \top$. The meet corresponds to conjunction (AND), and the join corresponds to disjunction (OR), though you can make a dual lattice with these flipped.

But, we don't teach this with boolean algebra for the same reason we don't teach group theory when teaching children about the whole numbers.

Lattice theory is *way* more than you need to understand booleans, and while it's a neat fact that booleans form a simple lattice, the mechanics of lattice theory, fixpoints, continuity, etc. were made to solve much harder problems than arise with booleans.